# What is the height of the skyscraper if...? (precalculus)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm currently reviewing for an exam next week and so I'm working on the practice test. Here's the problem:

If a skyscraper is viewed from the top of a 50' building, the angle of elevation is 59°. If it is viewed from the street level directly below the viewing point on the 50 foot building, the angle of elevation is 62°. Approximate the height of the skyscraper.

I drew a diagram of what I have but the farthest I got is: 
x = h/tan62°; h = xtan62°; h = y + 50'.

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hint: The first equation (and the equivalent second) is fine. Can you see that $\frac{h-50}{x}=\tan(59^\circ)$? Now use your equation and the one I just gave to "eliminate" $x$. That will give you an equation for $h$. Solve.

Comment: Thank you very much! As soon as you gave me that hint, it all makes sense to me. I got h approx. 434.45ft

Comment: You are welcome. Your number is right. A good outcome, the solution is primarily yours, not mine.